# Этимология слова «заурядный»

Tags: этимология, лексика

***Заурядный, обыкновенный и оригинальный, необычный*** имеют противоположное значение.

Но не очень ясно происхождение слова «заурядный», а именно значение **приставки ЗА.** В словарях говорится, что существовало слово «уряд», то есть порядок, устроение чего-либо. Но тогда заурядный – это тот, который находится **за пределами этого порядка**, что больше похоже на оригинальность и необыкновенность.

И вот дальнейшее толкование происхождения этого слова кажется мне **неубедительным и надуманным:** «заурядный — «замещающий» > «ненастоящий», а значит, и «посредственный, суррогатный».

Можно ли **иначе доказать**, что приставка ЗА связана с обозначением  именно обычного, а не оригинального?

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ от 12.05.2022**

1. **Спасибо всем** за участие в обсуждении вопроса: за ваши ответы, версии и прочее.
2. **Приставка ЗА** многозначная и действительно очень интересная, достаточно указать на то, что она может обозначать и начало, и завершение действия. Но при всех значениях просматривается **ее основной смысл** — это выход за пределы предмета, действия, признака. Именно его нужно увидеть в слове "заурядный".
3. Я особо благодарю участников, **давших ответы** (ставлю им плюсы). Все ваши рассуждения интересны, они прояснили мне и мою позицию. Но вот с окончательными выводами я все-таки не согласна: (1) зашедший в ряд, задействованный в ряду других; (2) слово зауряд часто использовалось в значении "заодно с кем-то" или "все подряд". Вот тут уже вполне себе просвечивает значение — такой, как все, заодно с другими.
4. Хотелось бы услышать и **другие версии** в окончательном виде, особенно от наших активных участников.
5. У меня теперь есть **свой вариант ответа**, который сложился после обсуждения и просмотра всех материалов дискуссии, но я его опубликую чуть позже. Здесь было интересное сообщение, на которое не обратили должного внимания, но оно мне показалось **ключом к решению задачи.**

P. S. Я отвечу на вопрос **завтра**, если других ответов не будет.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136247/discussion-on-question-by-sharon---).

Answer (score 1):

За-урядный, за-меститель. Тот, кто лишь замещает. Быть за кого-то. Кто сегодня за главного?

Comment: У приставки ЗА есть значение "вместо", но я не думаю, что оно сюда подходит.   Нужно идти от слова "уряд" – порядок, устроение.

Comment: Но ведь было же слово урядник - начальник. Может, оттуда?

Comment: ВСе эти слова с обыкновенностью никак не связаны, они связаны с порядком.  А обыкновенные как раз любят порядок.

Comment: Уряд был главным, следящим за порядком. Вместо него иногда ставили зауряда, т.е. человека, не выдающегося ничем.

Comment: Я это понимаю так: уряд - порядок, урядник следит за порядком.  Заместитель урядника - не настоящий урядник, но почему он обязательно посредственный?  Заместителей на всех должностях хватает, но почему-то заурядность приписали именно этому заместителю.

Comment: Действительно, не очень понятно, почему заместитель считается посредственностью, хотя есть еще и просто "пешки", стоящие в ряду. Может, все же была коннотация у слова, что-то вроде "хуже", "ненастоящий", "поддельный". Возьмем примеры из НКРЯ. Профессор (разумеется, настоящий, не зауряд, каковые, по несчастию, находятся и у нас), профессор, говорю я, есть человек, который посвятил жизнь свою исключительно какой-нибудь из многочисленных отраслей познаний человеческих, который, так сказать, ею и для нее живет. [И. М. Муравьев-Апостол.  (1821)

Comment: Второй пример: Вот вам и обе армии, каждая из семи рядов: одна палит, поднявши правые ноги, словно кочерги, другая улепетывает, а за ней гонится витязь на пряничном петухе, и, к довершению очарования, вверху крепость, в виде кабачка, с перечницами вместо башен, а внизу надпись с нелепыми возгласами зауряд-стихов. [А. А. Бестужев-Марлинский. Вадимов (1834)] Что такое здесь зауряд-стихи? Псевдо-стихи, может?

Comment: Еще такая версия: слово зауряд часто использовалось в значении "заодно с кем-то" или "все подряд". Вот тут уже вполне себе просвечивает значение - такой, как все, заодно с другими.

Comment: @Nadezhda зауряд-стихи — ничем не примечательные, см. второе значение: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4-

Answer (score 1):

В обзоре приставочных образований с глаголами перемещения приставке *за-* даются такие определения: «Заходити — двигаясь, отклоняться от основного направления; переходить какую-либо границу, грань, вторгаясь в чужие владения; перен. Отклоняясь от первоначального направления, попадать, углубляться <...>, зайти и заити — зайти за что-либо, за пределы чего-либо; зайти внутрь, углубиться в пределы чего-либо; проникнуть, попасть куда-либо». (Формирование семантической структуры приставки за-. З.И. Годизова. Вестник СПУ сер. 9. 2008).

Позже приставка *за-* «естественным образом стала обозначать и чрезмерность действия» с заходом за некий абстрактный объект, и длительность действия, первоначально проявившуюся в глаголах типа *заморити*, *замучити*.

*Заурядный* — зашедший в ряд, задействованный в ряду других. Приставочный блок *за-у-* (за-в-) значением противопоставил бы предложной паре *из-за*.

Comment: М.б. приставочный блок "за+у" дает слову "заурядный" значение: "в ряду подобных, но самый последний"?

Answer (score 1):

Ну хорошо, попробуем.

Возникла мысль о значении ***у, около, при,*** как в *за столом.*

То есть *заурядный человек* — это человек, ***находящийся при порядке.*** Делает, как принято, как все.

Comment: Ой, Артем, меня тут отвлекли, я и забыла ответить. У приставки ЗА нет значения "расположение рядом". Но вот выражение "за столом, за чаем, за обедом" интересно, его надо объяснять как  значение Т.п. и предлога ЗА.  18. чем. (в сочет. с глаг.: сидеть, стоять, находиться и т.п.). Указывает на предмет, около которого в непосредственной близости находится, размещается кто-л. для какого-л. действия, занятия. СИДЕТЬ ЗА СТОЛОМ.   Здесь как бы совмещены значения рядом и сзади.  Вроде бы "тепло", но окончательный вывод получается, как я думаю, неверный. http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=ЗА&all=x

Comment: Хм, но в Викисловаре есть значение приставки ЗА как соответствующей предлогу ЗА.

Comment: Вы  видели, сколько в словаре указано значений для предлога ЗА (28 значений). К примеру, за столом – это очень частное значение, так как там указано много подробностей. В конечном счете во всех словах нужно видеть центральное значение приставки и предлога  – сзади, за предметом. В остальных значениях приставки оно модифицируется.

Comment: В Викисловаре было восемь значений. ;)

Comment: Ну да, для приставки ЗА – 8 значений, а для предлога ЗА – 25 значений. А вот у Кузнецова есть интересный момент:  для приставки ЗА: 7 значений для глагола и только одно – для сущ. и прилаг. Обозначает: нахождение по ту сторону, позади, дальше чего-л. Задворки, запястье, заречье, загородный, заморский, заречный, защёчный.  Круг сужается...

Answer (score 1):

1. **Информация из словарей**

(1)  В «Большом этимологическом словаре русского языка» (2013) указано: ***Заурядный*** –   XV век, собственно русское от ***зауряд*** из ***уряд*** (управление, порядок) из рядить (править). Буквально: замещающий.

(2) [Викисловарь](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4-):

ЗАУРЯД-
***устар.*** при добавлении к существительным образует существительные со значением ‘занимающий должность **без соответствующего чина, диплома** и т. п.'

2. Но в XIX веке слово еще употреблялось **в прямом значении**: Профессор (разумеется, настоящий, **не зауряд**, каковые, по несчастию, находятся и у нас)… [И. М. Муравьев-Апостол. (1821)]
3. Итак, ***зауряд*** – это человек, занимающий должность **без диплома и чина**, то есть не по порядку. Другими словами, это обыкновенный человек, который **замещает специалиста**.  Уже потом появилось переносное значение – посредственный, обыкновенный.

Другими словами, ***зауряд*** (заурядный) непосредственно связан со словом «***уряд***» (порядок), но не со словом «***ряд***» в современном его понимании. Он «не заодно с другими, не действует в ряду других, не делает, как принято, как все».

А именно такими были **окончательные выводы** участников, отнесенные к слову «ряд», а не к слову «уряд».

5. Обратимся еще раз **к словарю Шанского:**

**ЗАУРЯДНЫЙ** Искон. Суф. образование от зауряд «исполняющий обязанности», преф. производного от уряд «порядок, управление» (от урядить «учредить, устроить»), образованного в свою очередь от рядить «править». См. ряд, урядник, порядок. Заурядный буквально — «замещающий» > «ненастоящий» (а значит, и «посредственный, суррогатный»).

6. Объяснение корректное, но не очень ясное. Лучше было бы написать так: ***Заурядный*** буквально — **заместитель,** занимающий должность без диплома и чина, что не соответствует порядку (уряду), находится за пределами порядка.
   Именно такое значение имеет приставка ЗА (**за пределами порядка, а не ряда**). И уже затем – ненастоящий, посредственный, обыкновенный, ничем не выдающийся.

Comment: Я-то связывал его со словом "уряд" как раз, а не "ряд". И смотрел в ваше определение уряда.

Comment: @Артём Луговой  Да, связывали с урядом, поэтому я написала: Вроде бы "тепло", но окончательный вывод получается, как я думаю, неверный.  А вывод был такой: "Делает, как принято, как все." Ключиком же я называла фразу: заместитель, занимающий должность БЕЗ ДИПЛОМА И ЧИНА, что не соответствует ПОРЯДКУ (уряду). Вот ее надо было найти. У вас же указана связь с урядом (порядком), а потом вы делаете вывод на основании общего "ряда".  Рассуждения правильные, а вывод такой же, как у всех.

Comment: Интересно то, что у нас сейчас таких "заурядов", вероятно, хватает, и,возможно, они не хуже специалистов и совсем незаурядные. Но тем не менее "зауряды" в прямом значении.

Comment: Действительно, интересно))

Comment: Еще интересен такой ПСИХОЛОГИЧЕСКИЙ момент. Я самого начала связывала значение "заурядный" со словом "ряд" и практически до самого последнего момента не меняла свое мнение. Но этот "посыл" оказался ложным (я потом это поняла), но остальные участники так и не смогли освободиться от этой установки, хотя в своих рассуждениях были очень близки к истине. Вот этот своеобразный  "массовый гипноз" интересен в общем плане. Как часто такое происходит?  То есть чье-то  (в том числе собственное) ложное утверждение принимается за аксиому, и уйти он неё довольно сложно.